# jQuery Animate a div on click

Tags: html, click, jquery-animate, fade

I want to make a `div` slide 200px to the left and make another `div` fade in on click, but it doesn't work.

This is the code I tried:

```
<script>          
    $("#navigatie").click(function () {
        $(".tekstblock:hidden:first").delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#navigatie").animate({"left":"200px"}, "1s");
    });
</script>

<div id="navigatie">
    <div class="button" id="button"><p>Over ons</p></div>
    <div class="button" id="upright"><p>audio</p></div>
    <div class="button" id="downleft"><p>Gallery</p></div>
    <div class="button" id="downright"><p>contact</p></div>
</div>
```

When I change:

`$("#navigatie").click(function () {`

to

`$("div").click(function () {`

the whole animation works perfectly, but the click function then applies it to all `div` tags.

I need to make it respond to the #navigatie `div` only.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not clear but [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULcFW/) might help. you have to give `postion:absolute` to #navigatie(the element which you are going to change postion using animate)